# Repeat div tags in specific number of sets from angularjs in html code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following div tag which I want to repeat multiple times

```
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-3 " style="margin-right:-50px;" ng-repeat="(key, value) in products.slice(4, 8) track by $index">
             <img src= {{value.imageUrl}} alt="No Image"/>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I want repeat the above entire div tag multiple times where each div tag displays 4 images at a time i.e the next div tag will have ng-repeat="(key, value) in products.slice(8, 12) track by $index"  and so on till there are images in the value object. How can this be achieved using angularjs?
Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should prepare the data better in the controller that's providing the `products` array. You could probably do this all inline but my guess is it would be pretty nasty.

Here's my suggestion.

The bottom code would provide you with arrays each with four entries of your images. You could change that by modifying the `count` variable and the reset inide the loop.

ExampleController.js

```
'use strict';

app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var products = [
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'},
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'},
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'},
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'},
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'},
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'},
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'},
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'},
            {'name':'Test','url':'some_image.jpg'}
        ];

        var products_page = [];
        var products_pages = [];
        var count = 4;

        $scope.products_pages = products_pages;

        for(var i=0;i<products.length;i++){
            if(count > 1){
                products_page.push(products[i]);
                count--;
                if(products.length === i+1){
                    products_pages.push(products_page);
                    return;
                }
            }else{
                products_page.push(products[i]);
                products_pages.push(products_page);
                products_page = [];
                count = 4;
            }
        }
});
```

Now with this out of the way you could do the following in the HTML.

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="page in products_pages">
      <div class="col-xs-3 " style="margin-right:-50px;" ng-repeat="image in page">
             <img src= {{image.url}} alt="No Image" />
      </div>
 </div>
```

Haven't tested it but I think this should do the trick. If you need it to be all inline, somebody else will have to pitch in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i want the <div class= item> to be repeated as well , does your code do that.

Comment: It doesn't, but as far as I can gather from your question you're trying to repeat a container and display 4 images in each repeated container incrementing through the array by 4. Is that right?

Comment: I need the entire div tag starting from the <div class="item"> to be repeated.

Comment: Do you understand what my example does and how it relates to your question? It should be very easy and obvious for you to get from what I'posted to what you seem to be asking for but I have a feeling you are not going bo know how to implement it since you seem to not be familiar with angular. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tweaked your code to the following and it worked.         <div class="item" ng-repeat="page in products_pages">
          <div class="col-xs-3 " style="margin-right:-50px;" ng-repeat="image in page">
            <img  src= {{image.imageUrl}} alt="No Image" />
            <a href="#"><h6>{{image.productName}}</h6></a>
          </div>
 </div> .

Comment: I did get the desired result but also in the firebug I am getting the below error. "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8100/static/html/%7B%7Bimage.url%7D%7D"         All the required images are getting displayed but I am not sure why this error comes up, and it gets displayed twice. Appreciate if you could help me.